# Gmail API - Fetches incomplete Raw data for mails with attachments > 5MB

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

The GMAIL API "**Users.messages: get**" doesn't fetches the complete raw data for the mails having more than 5MB attachments which in turn throws "*Unterminated string literal*" due to incomplete JSON.

```
function insertMessage(messageId) {
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/" + messageId + "?format=raw&fields=raw";
        var headers = {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        }
        var params = {
                method: "get",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: headers,
                muteHttpExceptions: true
        }
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
        var rawMsg = JSON.parse(response)["raw"].toString().replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/');
}
```

The above works perfectly for mails without attachments or with attachments which are below 5MB.

If I change to the below line there won't be any error but the mail attachments in case of excel gets corrupted and in case of images some are not included.

```
var rawMsg = JSON.parse(response+'"}')["raw"].toString().replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/');
```

I have already raised issue in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67467848). Is there any alternate way to fetch raw data along with all attachments?

Comment: Very interesting. I don't think there is any other way to get the `raw` message. Have you looked into getting the message in the `full` format instead, parsing it, and extracting the attachment ids? [**This code**](https://github.com/EmilTholin/gmail-api-parse-message/blob/master/lib/index.js) might give some inspiration.